# How would I have irb require the config/boot.rb file from the directory I run irb in?

Tags: ruby, irb

In every directory that I run irb, I have a config/boot.rb file that needs to be required.  It be great if this could be autoloaded when I enter irb, but I'm not sure how to refer to the directory that I opened irb in from the .irbc file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do:

```
 config_file = File.join(Dir.pwd, 'config', 'boot.rb')
 require config_file if File.exist?(config_file)
```

Answer (score 1):

That should be your current directory:

```
Dir.pwd
```

If you want, you could just require it like this:

```
require File.expand_path('config/boot.rb', Dir.pwd)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `irb -r`.

```
$ irb -r./config/boot
```

Bonus points if you bind it to a bash alias.

```
$ alias bootirb=irb -r./config/boot
```

You won't be modifying your *.irbrc* this way—I'd imagine some people may find this to be a cleaner approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current directory of the process with `Dir.pwd` and that should be the same as the directory where you run the irbc command.  Try putting something like this in .irbc:

```
require Dir.pwd + '/config/boot.rb'
```